# search rows with conditions on children rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `invoice` and `invoice_product`

In the table `invoice_product` there is a column `serialno`

How to search for invoices that contain a product with a specific serial number?

Comment: Perhaps reading [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although difficult to provide a full working example, replacing the fields in the following query with what you need from `invoices` should do the trick:

```
    SELECT i.id
      FROM invoice i
INNER JOIN invoice_product ip ON ip.invoice_id = i.id
     WHERE ip.serialno = 'YOUR_NUMBER'
  GROUP BY i.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you should have the `invoiceno` column in both `invoice` and `invoice_product` tables. Then you can combine two tables using `invoiceno` column.

you can use this following code to get that specific Invoices according to the product serial no

```
SELECT invoice.invoiceno FROM invoice 
INNER JOIN invoice_product ON invoice.invoiceno=invoice_product.invoiceno 
WHERE invoice_product.serialno='12345'
```